# Multiple Right Join Issue in Ms Access SQL, Returns SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having some issues with (I think) the SQL. I'm no expert here but have read that multiple joins need to be wrapped in parenthesis, however I just cannot make this work.

Maybe this isn't even the issue, this is most likely down to me not fully understanding exactly what is going on here! If someone could tell me what stupid thing I've done here that'd be great!

When I open the form where the listbox is referencing this query *ComponentFinalHomeListboxQuery* I get:

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
>   '[DatabaseComponentID] ='.

The list still populates but displays the error before each record appears in the listbox.

Changing the join between `ComponentMasterCostQuery.DatabaseComponentID` and  `Components.MasterDatabasecomponentID` from right to inner fixes the error but does not display the records that I need. I am trying to display all records from the *Components* table and only those from *ComponentMasterCostQuerywhere* the fields are equal.

When the user adds a component to the database I need it to appear in this listbox so they can select it and add other related information stored in other tables. Once this information has all been entered the *ComponentMasterCostQuery* calculates the cost to manufacture the component, the *ComponentFinalHomeListboxQuery* picks this up and displays a cost in the listbox with the item.

- *Components* is the master table containing all the component Id's, names and types (pulled from the *ComponentTypes* table).
- *ComponentTypes* simply is a list of types that each component is assigned.

Here is the SQL from the query in question:

```
SELECT
    ComponentMasterCostQuery.DatabaseComponentID
  , Components.KadComponentID
  , Components.ComponentName
  , ComponentTypes.Type
  , ComponentMasterCostQuery.PerPartMaterialCost
  , ComponentMasterCostQuery.OperationsCost
  , ComponentMasterCostQuery.TotalManufactureCost
FROM
    ComponentTypes
    RIGHT JOIN
        (ComponentMasterCostQuery
        RIGHT JOIN
            Components
        ON
            ComponentMasterCostQuery.DatabaseComponentID = Components.MasterDatabasecomponentID)
    ON
        ComponentTypes.ID = Components.ComponentType
```

Apologies if this is something silly, in fumbling my way through access learning from my mistakes!

Thanks for reading if you got this far!
Ryan

Comment: Build with query designer to get syntax right. Missing a parenthesis or 1 too many. Must be in pairs. And missing = sign.

Comment: This was built with the designer, I think I must have deleted them out by accident somehow when I pasted the code here, here it is as it is:

Comment: SELECT ComponentMasterCostQuery.DatabaseComponentID, Components.KadComponentID, Components.ComponentName, ComponentTypes.Type, ComponentMasterCostQuery.PerPartMaterialCost, ComponentMasterCostQuery.OperationsCost, ComponentMasterCostQuery.TotalManufactureCost
FROM ComponentTypes RIGHT JOIN (ComponentMasterCostQuery RIGHT JOIN Components ON ComponentMasterCostQuery.DatabaseComponentID = Components.MasterDatabasecomponentID) ON ComponentTypes.ID = Components.ComponentType;

Comment: Then edit your question as well.

Comment: Question is edited :)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and folliw the suggestions there about [ask], etc.Especially sample data (as text!) and desired result will help us to help you ;) Clean up your question and comments (delete the solved syntax error or put the old sql in front for context and delete the comment with the sql code)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `=`.  But aliases make the query easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT cmcq.DatabaseComponentID,  c.KadComponentID, c.ComponentName, ct.Type, 
       cmcq.PerPartMaterialCost, cmcq.OperationsCost, cmcq.TotalManufactureCost
FROM ComponentTypes as ct RIGHT JOIN
     (ComponentMasterCostQuery as cmcq RIGHT JOIN
      Components as c
      ON cmcq.DatabaseComponentID = c.MasterDatabasecomponentID
     )
     ON ct.ID = c.ComponentType;
```

I much prefer `LEFT JOIN`.  In fact, I almost never use `RIGHT JOIN`s.  But I did not change your query.

Comment: Ah that's a handy! Ok so would this potentially be causing my error?

Comment: The lack of `=` is the most likely cause of your error.